# I need to find specific variables that the user has inputted however I don't comprehend how

Tags: java, arrays, input

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int amount = 0;
    int input = 0;
    int[] numbers =  new int [amount];

    for(int i = 0; i<1; i++ )
    {
        System.out.println("How many numbers do you plan to enter?");
        amount = scan.nextInt(); 
        if (amount==amount)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x<amount; x++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter a number");
                input = scan.nextInt();
                input = input + input;

            }
        }

    }
    double average = input/amount;
    System.out.println(average);
```

}
}

I want to every number the user inputs, but how would I go about that?
For example, if the input is a 2 then a 3 then a 4 how do i take those and print them out in the next line while stating their averages.

Comment: What was `if (amount==amount)` supposed to accomplish?  Also, `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)` -- why is that there, and what is the purpose of `i`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with the code as you have written it.

1. `if (amount == amount)` is the same as saying `if (true)`, so you might as well remove it.
2. You are doubling your input for no particular reason.
3. You are trying to build an array to store the amount **before** knowing how big it needs to be.
4. Your outer `for` loop is looping exactly once, so you do not need that either.

Here is a working and simplified revision of your code.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int amount = 0;
        int total = 0;

        System.out.println("How many numbers do you plan to enter?");
        amount = scan.nextInt(); 
        // Now that we know the amount, we can build an array to hold that
        // amount.
        int[] numbers =  new int [amount]; 
        for(int x = 0; x<amount; x++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a number");
            numbers[x] = scan.nextInt();
            total += numbers[x];
        }
        double average = total * 1.0 /amount; // Prevent integer division
        System.out.println(average);
    }
}
```

Update: The code above will compute the average of the numbers that the user has provide.
The OP seems to hint that he wants the proportion of each input instead. Here is a modification using `HashMap` to accomplish that.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int amount = 0;
        int total = 0;

        // Create a Map to get the count of each input.
        Map<Integer,Integer> counts = new TreeMap<Integer,Integer>();

        System.out.println("How many numbers do you plan to enter?");
        amount = scan.nextInt(); 
        for(int x = 0; x<amount; x++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a number");
            int input = scan.nextInt();
            if (counts.containsKey(input)) counts.put(input, counts.get(input) + 1);
            else counts.put(input,1);
        }

        // Print out the percentage of each input
        for (Integer key : counts.keySet())
            System.out.printf("%d\t%.2f%%\n", key, counts.get(key) * 100.0 / amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: I still don't quite see how to seclude the specific input and then find the average of each numbers % of usage which is my main objective

Comment: @user3466743, The specific input lives inside the `numbers` array. Are you trying to find the proportion of `input` which is a particular number?

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt your code to not even have to ask how many numbers you plan to enter.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println("Please enter some numbers, n to terminate: ");

        while(kb.hasNextInt())
            values.add(kb.nextInt());

        System.out.println("\nYou entered the following values:");

        double runningSum = 0;

        for(int elem : values) {
            runningSum += elem;
            System.out.print(elem + " ");
        }

        System.out.println("\nThe average of the values entered is: "
                + runningSum / values.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: I still don't quite see how to seclude the specific input and then find the average of each numbers % of usage which is my main objective.

Comment: See the modified code. Basically, you loop through the array and compute a running sum of each element. Then you divide this sum by the length of the array.